# New Contact change

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to change the create/new functionality for Contact. Basically, I want to have the User who is creating the contact to select the contact owner from a lookup. I thought this would be more straight forward, but I'm having trouble making it happen.

I tried creating an extension and a VF page for Contact. Modifying the New button for Contact to use that VF page. I get the VF page to show up after selecting the recordType. Do I need to add Contact inputfields on my VF page to recreate the standard new page for Contacts + a value for Contact Owner? It seems like there should be an easier way.

**One reason this is difficult trying to do it using an extension and VF page is that with 6 different recordTypes and pagelayouts I would have to recreate new VF layout for each. Basically I just need to allow the user to select another user as owner when creating a new Contact.

Has anyone had any experience doing this and can suggest best path forward?

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your post to be more specific about what you have tried so far and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd create a custom field, called New Contact Owner, and make a look up to the User object. From there, you can write a Process Builder to copy the New Contact Owner field to the Owner field when it is populated. This avoids the mess of having to write any code at all, and you can use all standard functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sfdcfox. I considered using it but ended up overriding the new button for Contact to go to a VF page, save the Contact and then forward to the Contact detail page. Both ways are viable options I believe.